# C# Trim spaces inside array (remove 0's)

Tags: c#, arrays, trim

If I have the next array:

```
int[] arr = { 123, 243, 0, 0, 123, 0, 0, 0, 123 };
```

How can I move all the values which are not equal to 0 left as they can so the array will be built like this:

```
int[] arr = { 123, 243, 123, 123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I'd perform some kind of bubble-sort. There is no built in call for this, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OrderBy:

```
int[] arr = { 123, 243, 0, 0, 123, 0, 0, 0, 123 }.OrderBy(x => x == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Another nice one! Order of booleans is false then true, so this does work! +1

Answer (score 12):

How about with LINQ:

```
var result = arr.Where(x => x != 0).Concat(arr.Where(x => x == 0)).ToArray();
```

This is quite readable and has linear time complexity. On the other hand, it runs out-of-place and requires two passes over the input.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers so far create a new array. Really you can just move the items up in a single loop and then fill the rest with 0s.

```
public static void ShiftZerosRight(this int[] arr)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (j < arr.Length && arr[j] != 0)
    {
        j++;
    }
    for (int i = j; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != 0)
        {
            arr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    while (j < arr.Length)
    {
        arr[j++] = 0;    
    }
}
```

Not as elegant as the single line LINQ expressions, but more efficient - this does not create any new objects (and LINQ creates several and the final new array) and this is a single pass through the array. As an extension method the complexity is not seen in the main body where it can be used as:

```
int arr[] = { ... };
arr.ShiftZerosRight();
```

Comment: this code will not work. this will fail in first step if array has 0 has start arr[j] != 0

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using Linq with:

```
        int[] arr = { 123, 243, 0, 0, 123, 0, 0, 0, 123 };

        arr = arr.OrderByDescending(a => a > 0).ToArray<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr.OrderBy(x=>x == 0).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new array and transfer the values to it.

```
int[] newArr = new int[arr.Length];
int i = 0;
foreach ( var v in arr )
{
    if (v != 0) 
    {
        newArr[i++] = v;
    }
}
arr = newArr;
```

Since `int` is a value type the array is initialized with all zeroes. Then we copy the values one at a time only increasing the destination index `i` if the value is not 0. More verbose than the Linq examples shown, and decidedly uncooler. But if you're a student it might be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet doesn't create another array.Here 'x[]' is your array. You take the 1st 0 value and replace it with a non zero number.

```
int i=0,j=0,index=0,temp=0;
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    if(x[i]==0)
    {
       index=i;
       for(j=index;j<x.length;j++)
       {
          if(x[j]!=0)
          {
            temp=x[j];
            x[j]=x[i];
            x[i]=temp;
            break;
          }
       }
    }
}
```